# Android Textview ellipsize with multiple rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get an ellips at the end of a textview that has multiple lines of text. The "..." is showing but its at the last space in the text and is other followed by other characters. How do I make sure the "..." is always at the end.

See example image[image]

The XML Layout file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nfDateMonth"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/topsegment"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="APR"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#f2e606"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nfDateDate"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nfDateMonth"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottomsegment"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="28"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nfTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nfDateMonth"
    android:text="Half Marathon"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nfContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nfTitle"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nfDateDate"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Content\nline two line three sadsa dsd dsa dsd big big big sd sad sad sadsadsad asd sad as d asd as das das das das da sd asd asd one two three four five sixx seven"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I ran your code but didn't find the problem that you have mentioned.

Comment: Maybe its a device thing because as the image shows, I clearly do get the problem..

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue today. It's probably bug in TextView or TextUtils (method ellipsize).
In my case it's caused by text with new lines.

There are two solutions:

1. Get first line only:

```
String longText = "...";
String body = new Scanner(longText).nextLine();
textView.setText(body);
```

2. Remove all new lines in text

```
String longText = "...";
String body = longText.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
textView.setText(body);
```